# Suspiscious router log entry...please help

Tags: logging

I noticed a strange web address in my router log.  Can anyone help me understand what this is?

```
Site allowed: redir.adap.tv] from source 192.168.1.7, Thursday, May 05,2016 11:57:27
[Site allowed: ad4.liverail.com] from source 192.168.1.7, Thursday, May 05,2016 11:57:27
[Site allowed: c2s-openrtb.liverail.com] from source 192.168.1.7, Thursday, May 05,2016 11:57:27
[Site allowed: c2s-ope,xP�c����C/{,��?�%�J1�ޜX����Nh@�5x�m��`�...]
```

Comment: Do you mean the last line with the corrupted-looking data?

Comment: Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Pro Webmasters. You may be able to get help on [sf]. As your question is currently written it *probably* would not meet that site's quality guidelines. I recommend reading their [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/about) to ensure your question is appropriate for their site.